# ReactJs :Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Whenever i am adding the `if(IsLogged()){...}` block I am getting this error.

> Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate.
>   React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

I've read other similar question here but I'm not able to understand whatI'm doing wrong.

I'm a newbie to React Js so please bear with me.

```
render() {
        if (IsLogged()) {
            return <Redirect to="/" />;
        }
        return (
            <Grid
                textAlign="center"
                style={{ height: "75vh" }}
                verticalAlign="middle"
            >
                <Grid.Column style={{ maxWidth: 450 }} columns={2}>
                    <Segment>
                        <Grid.Row>
                            <Header as="h1" color="teal" textAlign="center">
                                Log In
                            </Header>
                        </Grid.Row>
                        <Form
                            onSubmit={this.submitLogin}
                            style={{ paddingTop: "1rem" }}
                        >
                            <Form.Input
                                icon="mail"
                                iconPosition="left"
                                placeholder="Email"
                                fluid
                                value={this.state.email}
                                onChange={(e) =>
                                    this.setState({ email: e.target.value })
                                }
                            />

                            <Form.Input
                                icon="lock"
                                iconPosition="left"
                                fluid
                                placeholder="Password"
                                type="password"
                                value={this.state.password}
                                onChange={(e) =>
                                    this.setState({
                                        password: e.target.value,
                                    })
                                }
                            />

                            <Button color="teal" fluid size="large">
                                Log In
                            </Button>
                        </Form>
                        <Grid.Row style={{ paddingTop: "1rem" }}>
                            <div style={{ marginTop: "1rem" }}>
                                Not Singed In Yet?
                                <Link to="/signup">Sign Up</Link>
                            </div>
                        </Grid.Row>
                    </Segment>
                </Grid.Column>
            </Grid>
        );
```

```
function IsLogged() {
    let token = sessionStorage.getItem("jwtToken");

    if (!token || token === ""|| token === null || typeof token ==="undefined") {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

export default IsLogged;
```

Comment: The issue seems to be related to Redirect. However to solve it, we need more info regarding how the component is structured and how routes are handled

Comment: Also, post the code of the `IsLogged` function if possible

Comment: Always try to post all related code (without sensitive content) so the reader can understand the code easily without assuming things.

Comment: @ShanakaRusith I think I solved the issue. You see after removing the multiple checks in the IsLogged function it started to redirect correctly. But I still dont get why that happens?

Comment: Do you render This component on the home page?

If you do, I am thinking this `<Redirect />` might render each time and try to redirect to the home page again and again.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your `onChange` handlers to include `e.preventDefault();` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

```
onChange={(e) => {
  e.preventDefault();        
  // setState here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error also might happen when you are using `setState()` in render block, and then it causes infinite rerender. What is inside your `isLogged()` function? Most probably you should check is user logged with true/false variable, neither executing a function in render block, that might cause infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is your IsLogeed method ? But try with ...

```
if (!IsLogged()) {
        return <Redirect to="/" />;
    }
```